# Is there a way to separate user created methods vs Backbone methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example when creating models, you might have domain specific logic that needs to be implemented in the Model definition.  Backbone of course has its own methods, which you may define which have special meaning such as `initialize()`.  Is there a way to separate them, such as a naming convention?  Would this be a good idea?

For example:

**Backbone Function**

```
initialize: function () {
    //  Backbone will run this as it is defined in the library
},
```

**User Function**

```
userFunc: function () {
    // this is defined and used only by the user 
},
```

Comment: There are no conventions for that, really. Just pick your own style and be consistent.

Comment: so you need to separate model methods, for example if user registered model have one methods set if not another one, did i get your idea right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some(your own) naming convention, that's the only way as far as my knowledge.
You can prefix the function names you create by the current project. Like if my current project is 'ZZZZ' and my function names can be....

> ZZZZerrorHandler : function(){}
>
> ZZZZuserButtonClick : function(){}
>
> ZZZZgoBackClicked : function(){}

This helps you to identify the user-defined and backbone-default functions.